# How To Get Nginx Client Ip Using Revese Proxy (Django, Nginx, Gunicorn)

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx, http-headers, ip

I'm facing an issue with retrieving the client IP addresses from the X-Forwarded-For header when using Nginx as a reverse proxy server in front of my Django application. Currently, I'm only able to obtain the IP address of the Nginx proxy server instead of the actual client's IP.

I have configured Nginx to set the necessary headers using the following directives:

```bash
server {
        server_name example.domain.com;
        set_real_ip_from 0.0.0.0/0;
        real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
        real_ip_recursive on;


        location /static/ {
                root /home/user/example.domain.com/djangoapp;
        }

        location / {
                proxy_set_header  Host $host;
                proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto https;
                proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_pass http://10.0.0.122:8000;
        }
}
```

I have tried it all, even using the map from this artlcle and alot more:
[link](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/forwarded/)

### but the X-Forwarded-For and X-Real-IP are still the proxy server's IP and not the client IP! can't even get it to return a list and not just the last IP...

In my Django view, I'm trying to access the client IP using request.META.get('HTTP_X_REAL_IP') and request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR'). The headers are showing, but not the client's IP.

```json
{
 'Content-Length': '',
 'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
 'X-Real-Ip': '10.0.0.101',
 'X-Forwarded-Proto': 'https',
 'X-Forwarded-For': '10.0.0.101',
 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 ...',
```

## even the user agenst is correct. but the IPs are not.

I have also checked that the X-Forwarded-For header is being correctly forwarded by Nginx to the Django application. However, I'm still unable to retrieve the actual client IP address.

Maybe something is not trusted, I can't get full list...

## Could you help? ty for reading :)